# Horizontal curve over an arithmetic surface

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Im' working on the book of Lang "introduction to arakelov theory".

In the 4th chapter "Hodge index and adjunction formula" p. 99 Lang gives the following :

Let $X$ be an arithmetic surface over the ring of integers of a number field, and let $E$ an horizontal curve over X.

I have been looking for the definition of a curve on an artihmetic surface since this morning. Is it just a divisor? Because i know what's a horizontal divisor !

Thanks for help !

Comment: A curve on a surface determines a divisor. So yes, I think an horizontal curve means a curve whose divisor is horizontal

Comment: ok ! thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: You will probably find Liu's book https://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Geometry-Arithmetic-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0199202494 quite helpful when reading Lang's book.

Comment: I will, thanks :)